# Is it possible to setup sign in to Azure AD by google account?

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, google-account

In my organization I have Azure AD sync to organization AD.
Is it possible to add authentication by Google account for external users?
Azure AD is using by mobile app to authenticate in moblie backend. 
(I know about https://auth0.com/lock, but administrators prefer Azure AD)

Thanks!

Comment: Check Azure AD B2C whether it's suitable for your case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yuiry, like Cuong mentioned, [Azure B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-b2b-what-is-azure-ad-b2b) can be used to provide integration with social accounts, including Google and Facebook.

A second option is to use [Azure B2B](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory-b2c) - which is to invite users as **guests** to your organization - this different than the first option because a *guest Google user* ends up being identified as a *Microsoft Account using a Gmail email address* as and not a real Google account - which effectively means that they will have a different accounts/ passwords.

Comment: Is it possible to not have MS account?